# How to solve a differential equation with non-constant coefficient?

Tags: matlab, differential-equations

I have an equation like this:

```
dy/dx = a(x)*y + b
```

where `a(x)` is a non-constant (`a=1/x`) and `b` is a vector (10000 rows).

How can I solve this equation?

Comment: You don't need MATLAB to solve this: you can use an [integrating factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor) to find a solution `y(x) = b*x*ln(x) + c*x` for some constant c.

Comment: even if b is a vector !!

Comment: `y` is 10000-by-1, `c` can be 10000-by-1, solution not valid for `x=0`

Answer (score 1):

Let me assume you would like to write a generic numerical solver for dy/dx = a(x)*y + b. Then you can pass the function a(x) as an argument to the right-hand side function of one of the ODE solvers. e.g.

```
a = @(x) 1/x;
xdomain = [1 10];
b = rand(10000,1);
y0 = ones(10000,1);
[x,y] = ode45(@(x,y,a,b)a(x)*y + b,xdomain,y0,[],a,b);
plot(x,y)
```

Here, I've specified the domain of `x` as `xdomain`, and the value of `y` at the bottom limit of x as `y0`.

Comment: I tried to simulate your code, but honestly I'm not sure I got the right result !!

Comment: Can you check the link plz

Comment: @Ar1 That looks fine, each entry of `y` has been plotted. What do you expect to see?

Comment: If for example I have this initial condition:
y (x = 50) = 0
How can I add it to my code?
In fact, I tried to add it but unfortunately an error msg is displayed indicating that the matrices don't have the same dimension ! Do you have any suggestion?  I so am grateful because both of you helped me :D

Comment: @Ar1 you would have `xdomain = [50 100]` (or whatever your `x` domain is), `y0 = zeros(10000,1)`.

Comment: hi all here is my code load ('Bx');
load ('By');
load ('Bz');
b= sqrt(Bx.^2+By.^2+Bz.^2);
fe=83333; 
Te=1/fe; 
N=length(Bz); 
t=0:Te:(N-1)*Te; 
t=t'; 
dB = diff(b)./diff(t); 
a = @(x) 1/x;
xdomain = linspace(1,100,10);
y0=1;
for i=1:numel(dB)
  f=@(x,y) -(a(x)*y+dB(i));
  [x,y]=ode45(f,xdomain,y0);
  yvec(i,:)=y(:);
end
figure (1)
subplot(2,2,1), plot(b,'c')
title('b= sqrt(Bx.^2+By.^2+Bz.^2)')
subplot(2,2,2), plot(dB,'m')
title('dB = -diff(b)./diff(t);')
subplot(2,2,3),plot (x,y,'k')
title ('solution ode45')

Comment: but i am not sure if i got the good result, here is the result of simulation

Answer (score 0):

From my comments, you can solve this without MATLAB. Assuming non-zero `x`, you can use an [integrating factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor) to get a 10000-by-1 solution `y(x)`

```
y_i(x) = b_i*x*ln(x) + c_i*x
```

with 10000-by-1 vector of constants `c`, where `y_i(x)`, `b_i` and `c_i` are the `i`-th entries of `y(x)`, `b` and `c` respectively. The constant vector `c` can be determined at some point `x0` as

```
c_i = y_i(x0)/x_0 - b_i*ln(x0)
```